# Spring Security authentication is ignored

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, basic-authentication

Hello Stackoverflower,

i've got a Issue with the Spring Security stuff. The Login Box that should appear before you can proceed to your application dont appear and i can access to my application without any authentication. I dont have any clue why this happen. 
It would be very important to know why no User and Password are asked.

I test my app with the RESTCLient Add on for firefox.

The important entry in the web.xml looks like:

```
<!--    Security Configuration -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Json Init -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>json</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>json</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My spring-security is:

```
<!-- Security Propertie Configuration -->
    <security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:http-basic/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="springUserService" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

The springUserService looks like this:

@Component
public class springUserService implements AuthenticationProvider {

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
  throws AuthenticationException {
    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);

}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

}

Im very thankfull for every Hint or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add some intercept url tag in your spring security config:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/securedUrl" access="isAuthenticated()" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
```

So change your code in something like this:

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/securedUrl" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
</security:http>
```

You can also use **wildcard** in pattern-attribute or custom access evaluation:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/url1/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')"/> 
<intercept-url pattern="/url2/**" access="isAuthenticated()" /> 
<intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" /> 
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you Tell me how to make a intercept url for a dynamic request ?  my url can be /rest/service/function. With the intercept url i will lose my Function call or not?

Comment: Use * for example /items/*

Comment: mserioli Thank you very much but i dont get it. The problem im facing is that i like to set my auth to a dynamic pattern but i have a idea how this will work for mine. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: I'd like to configure a authentification through my CustomUserservice who needs to ask everytime i try to call any Url after localhost for an authentification. 
E.g. localhost/service1 - Asks for Authentification
localhost/service2 - Asks for Authentification
The Url after localhost has tob be secured.

Comment: @ArturRem I don't know if it could be a good approach but you can try to specify multiple <url-pattern>/customUsrls</url-pattern> in filterMapping in web.xml

Comment: The Solution were Intercept URL i had some in my source and tested them but they didnt worked, i think the reason was my pattern but now it works pretty well. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" path-type="regex">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/.*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/.*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>
```

Here is a more detailed example with explanations:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" path-type="regex">
    <form-login 
        password-parameter="password" -- password field name in your form
        username-parameter="username" -- username field name in your form
        login-processing-url="/security/j_spring_security_check" -- where your login form should submit to, no need to map this to anything, Spring Security handles it
        login-page="/login" -- where you'll be taken to when not logged in
        authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" -- if your login fails, security will redirect you with login_error set to t
        default-target-url="/router" -- if you want to route people based on roles, etc, you can map a controller ot this URL 
        always-use-default-target="false" -- this will send logged in users to your router URL
         />
    <headers>
        <xss-protection/> -- inserts header to prevent prevents cross site scripting
    </headers>
    <logout logout-url="/security/j_spring_security_logout" /> -- logout url, no need ot map it to anything, handled by Spring Security

    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/.*"  access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" /> -- security URLs by roles
    <intercept-url pattern="/register"  access="permitAll"/>              -- let new users register by allowing everyone access to the registration page
    <intercept-url pattern="/.*"        access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https" />  -- require users to be authenticated for the rest of the page and require HTTPS (optional) for ALL urls
</http>
```

Comment: BIG TY but this seem very static right ? The most tags i even know but very nice work

Comment: @ArturRem - what do you mean by "very static"?  http element has `path-type="regex"` which means you can secure any URL pattern as long as you can express it using a regular expression (which is ANY pattern).

Comment: u mean the last row right ? with  pattern="/.*". I tried this one but it didnt worked for me yet. I have no login form. but maybe its the hierachie of the pattern URL. Thank you very very much saved my day i will tell if its working :-)